# PDF .js not loading first page in Safari

Tags: pdf, pdf.js

I managed to get pdf.js working in chrome and other browsers. However it doesn't seem to be loading properly in Safari. Safari doesn't load the first page of the PDF files. I've not modified any code in the pdf.js library. Any help?

Comment: Safari version? Link to PDF? Link to demo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there was an:

```
Warning: Unhandled rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: MozBlobBuilder
```

This occured because in the webkit version the `typeof Blob === "object"` when there is an image in the pdf being displayed and not the default (`typeof Blob === "function"`). To fix this issue we had to replace this line in util.js with `(typeof Blob !== 'undefined')`

Comment: This bug was already [fixed](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/commit/b96811df25913926cb686b6b0400bc92d58107fa) last month. Next time, when you encounter a bug in PDF.js, just pull the latest version from Github.